# MacOs, can't run MySqlServer from Preferences

Tags: mysql, macos

i'm facing a strange problem. I'm installing MySqlServer on my MacOs 10.13.

I tried installing it from the terminal using Brew, but it resulted on being stuck for 2 hours on 'installing dependencies', so i stopped it and installed with a .dmg from the site.

Now, to start the server i have to go in Preferences. But when i open them and click on 'MySqlServer', a message pops up that says 'to use the preferences panel "MySql", Preferences must be closed and restarted' (or something along the lines, i'm italinan so the message is in italian).

I can't go on in any way. Does anyone have a solution for this?